# Retrieving particular value from mongo documents using mongoose and nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am looking forward to check into the docs of the collection `model` and return a particular value, based on its key , from each one of them however i am missing something regarding the scope of how the model.find() actually works.

My documents within the `model` collection follow the following structure:

```
{_id: xxx,
 date: 2021-08-08T00:00:00.000+00:00
 data [array of data]}
```

And my code is as it follows

```
async (model, key) => {
  const getFilteredDataByKey = await model.find({}, (err, data)=> {
  data.map((doc) => doc[key]);
  });
  console.log('getFilteredDataByKey', getFilteredDataByKey)
  return getFilteredDataByKey;
};
```

The problem I am getting is that `getFilteredDataByKey` returns all the docs, when i guess it should return the filter uniquelly doesnt it?

My ideal output would be to return uniquely the array of the values, based on the keys,  from `getFilteredDataByKey`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `console.log` is returning an empty list since `model.find` is asynchronous, meaning the callback function has not been invoked yet.
I suggest you to use the following code and "await" the result instead of using a callback function:

```
const listado = (await model.find({}, 'date')).map(item => item.date);
console.log('listita',listado)
```

**Explanation:**
You first await the find function (you have to define your function as `async`) and only retrieve property 'date'. After that you map your document array to an array of plain dates.